# resource routes to be mapped to a custom path in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, custom-routes

I have a route like:

```
resources :products
```

Now I have all my code is in place but just need to change the paths from `/products/:action to /items/:action`

I have already skimmed through the rails docs but could not figure this out. It looks very basic and should be easy, but I just cant put my finger on it.

The url I used was: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can write your route like this:

```
resources :products, path: 'items'
```

This will generate `/items` routes with `product_*` named helpers, using `ProductsController`. Have a look at [this part of the Routing Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths).

Answer (score 13):

There are several ways you can accomplish this. One is to simply name your resource `items` and specify the controller with the `:controller` option.

```
resources :items, controller: 'products'
```

This will recognize incoming paths beginning with `/items` but route to the `ProductsController`. It will also generate route helpers based on the resource name (e.g. `items_path` and `new_item_path`).

Another way is to use the `:path` option when specifying the resource as pointed out by @dgiperez.

```
resources :products, path: 'items'
```

This will also route paths beginning with `/items` to the `ProductsController` but since the route helpers are based on the resource name, they would be based on *products* (e.g. `products_path` and `new_product_path`)

[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use)